# Custom post types with categories in template

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, templates

I´d like to do something like this:

Pages:
1. Sport
2. Business
3. Normal

Custom Category "Car-Types":
1. Audi
2. BMW
3. VW

My custom post type will called "Cars"

I´d like to show the cars by using a custom category like "Car-Type".
How can I filter the content from the custom categories, too and show it?

E. G.: On Page "Sport" should just show the content from "BMW".

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cars' ); // How can I add a category-filter to this?

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
    the_content();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cars' ); // How can I add a category-filter to this?
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Car-Types',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'Audi'
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
    the_content();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters